# Error al concatenar dos cadenas en una clase php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tengo una clase BD, para realizar consultas procesadas,conecto con la base de datos de la siguiente manera, muy normal.

```php
var $cadena = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=idCliente00XX";
var $user = "root";
var $password = "";
```

sin problemas me conecta, la cuestión es que necesito tener control sobre el nombre de la base de datos, se me ocurrio obtener el contenido de la variable cadena pero en dos variables concatenadas, de la siguiente forma:

```php
var $variable0 ="idCliente00XX";
var $variable1 = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=";
var $cadena = $variable1.$variable0;
```

pero me arroja un error de sintaxis, de la variable1, estoy concatenando de manera correcta pero me arroja ese error.

En concreto el error que me arroja es el siguiente:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$variable1' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usas, pues el colocar `var` es un tanto obsoleto e innecesario, hace mucho que no lo veía?

Comment: @Aprendiz uso la 5.5

Comment: Vaya trataré de aportar una respuesta, pero considera que usas una versión obsoleta que desde hace años no recibe ya ningún soporte

Comment: `var` fue [propuesta para ser declarada obsoleta en PHP 7.1 y para ser removida del núcleo de PHP 8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/var_deprecation) Hay 31 votos a favor y 23 en contra, por lo que es recomendable evitar su uso. De todos modos en PHP 5.5 esto debería funcionar: `$variable0 ="idCliente00XX"; $variable1 = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname="; $cadena = $variable1.$variable0;`

Comment: @A.Cedano asi la he intentado y me arroja el error ahora no en la concatenacion, sino desde la declaracion de la primer variable; lo recomendable seria subir de version php?

Comment: Claro, lo mejor es actualizar tu versión de PHP. Eso sí, cuando cambies de versión revisa tus logs de errores, porque puede que haya código viejo que empiece a fallar, como por ejemplo si usas la API `mysql_` para conectar a la Base de datos y cosas así. Cuando migras tienes que monitorizar y posiblemente tendrás que adaptar cierto código obsoleto. Pero es mejor trabajar en un entorno actualizado por la seguridad, el rendimiento, etc.